# graphlab: How to load a gzipped file into SFrame

Tags: python, compression, gzip, graphlab, sframe

I would like to read a gzipped csv file () to SFrame provided by GraphLab. 
https://dato.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.read_csv.html

I tried the following code, but it did not work.

```
import graphlab
import gzip
graphlab.SFrame.read_csv(gzip.open('file.csv.gz'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `gzip.open` part. SFrame detects that automatically.